# Unusual number of requests coming from this IP

Tags: feature-request, support, status-deferred

Not sure if I should go ask this on some other meta, just asking it on cstheory because this is my favorite stackexchange.

Today I have been getting the following error, a lot:

> We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP address right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

I have never gotten this error before.

I can't refresh to make it go away, I have to wait a bit and then referesh. This has slowed down my browsing. I don't think I am doing anything different in my browsing from usual activity, and I am definitely not running any scripts. Is there a common issue that leads to this that I can avoid?

Alternatively, is it possible to just modify that page with a ReCaptcha (Google does something similar when you query it too quickly) so that I can prove I am human and continue browsing right away instead of waiting a while? (I know... no patience on the internet!)

Comment: It's ok to ask here, SE staff monitors all metas (maybe a bit slower on week-ends). You might need to add some information about how you're connecting (ISP, any proxy that you're aware of, that kind of things). For privacy, you might want to send email to `team+cstheory@stackexchange.com` rather than post such information here.

Comment: I corrected the email above.  You can always just click the `contact us` link at the bottom of any page.

Answer (score 6):

Can you humor me and try in a different browser with a clean install (no extensions or plugins)? Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE9.. whatever works for you.

It's definitely unusual to get this unless you happen to be on a shared IP with a *lot* of extremely active users.

We do see it, however, from poorly written plugins and extensions quite a bit.

Comment: seems like I am unable to recreate the bug, today. So I doubt it was a browser issue, since that has not changed. If it happens again I will try with a clean browser and report back.